# How to display a record in a dataTable after saving in database?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

In SQL Server, I have a schema (ade) with some tables, which two of them are:

[image: picture of table Demandas and table Anotacoes]

I'm using Eclipselink ORM and Primefaces 6.2; I have a CRUD for both tables, which works fine.

In a **ListDemandas.jsf**, I have a datatable where the user can insert a new Demandas registry by clicking in a button. Then, a Dialog (located in the 
**CreateDemandas.jsf**) is displayed to input data in some fields. After clicking on a save button, such Dialog is hidden and the datatable is updated, showing this new Demandas record; the same action occurs to the Anotacoes entity, using a **ListAnotacoes.jsf** and a **CreateAnotacoes.jsf** .

**What I want** is to insert Anotacoes registries through the **ListDemandas.jsf** page and, right after saving that new Anotacoes registry, it would be displayed in the Demandas datatable (which is in the **ListDemandas.jsf** page).

What I achieved so far to do it: I put a button in the **ListDemandas.jsf** to invoke the Dialog (located in **CreateAnotacoes.jsf**). After clicking on a save button in such Dialog, this (Anotacoes) Dialog is hidden and the data is correctly persisted in the database.

The problem is that this new Anotacoes record is not being displayed in the Demandas datatable, even updating as below:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{anotacoesController.saveNew}" value="Save" update="display,:DemandasListForm:datalist,:DemandasListForm:DemandasDataTableContextMenu,:growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(xhr,status,args,PF('AnotacaoCreateDialog'));" >
```

The ListDemandas.jsf:

```
<h:form id="DemandasListForm">

    <p:panel id="PanelListForm" header="#{adeBundle.ListDemandasTitle}">

        <p:commandButton id="createButton"         value="Create Demanda"  update=":DemandasCreateForm" oncomplete="PF('DemandasCreateDialog').show()" actionListener="#{demandasController.prepareCreate}" />
        <p:commandButton id="createAnotacaoButton" value="Create Anotacao" update=":AnotacaoCreateForm, datalist" oncomplete="PF('AnotacaoCreateDialog').show()" />

        <p:dataTable id="datalist"
                     value="#{demandasController.items}"
                     lazy="false"
                     rowKey="#{item.id}"
                     var="item"
                     selection="#{demandasController.selected}"
                     widgetVar="demandasTable">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="@form:createAnotacaoButton, @form:createButton" listener="#{demandasController.resetParents}"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@form:createAnotacaoButton, @form:createButton" listener="#{demandasController.resetParents}"/>
            <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update="@form:createAnotacaoButton, @form:createButton" listener="#{demandasController.resetParents}"/>

            <p:column id="idCod" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="id"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <!-- some columns ommited -->    

            <p:rowExpansion>
                <p:panelGrid>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:accordionPanel value="Mais informacoes da Demanda" multiple="true">
                                <p:tab title="Anotacoes}" >
                                    <p:dataList value="#{item.anotacoesCollection}" var="anotacoesCollectionItem" itemType="none" emptyMessage="-" >
                                        <h:outputText value="#{anotacoesCollectionItem.anotacao.toString()}" />
                                    </p:dataList>
                                </p:tab>
                            </p:accordionPanel>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:column>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/include/confirmation.xhtml"/>    
</h:form>
```

The CreateAnotacao.jsf:

```
    <p:dialog id="AnotacaoCreateDlg" widgetVar="AnotacaoCreateDialog" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)" header="Create Anotacoes" >

    <h:form id="AnotacaoCreateForm" >

        <h:panelGroup id="display" >
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="column">

                <p:outputLabel value="CreateAnotacoesLabel_anotacao" for="anotacao" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:inputTextarea id="anotacao" value="#{anotacoesController.selected.anotacao}" title="CreateAnotacoesTitle_anotacao" />
                </h:panelGroup>

                <p:outputLabel value="CreateAnotacoesLabel_date" for="date" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:calendar id="date" value="#{demandasController.currentDate}" title="CreateAnotacoesTitle_date" />
                </h:panelGroup>

        <!-- some other input fields ommited -->                

            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{anotacoesController.saveNew}" value="Save" update="display, :DemandasListForm:datalist, :growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(xhr,status,args,PF('AnotacaoCreateDialog'));" >
            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure ?" />
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="PF('AnotacaoCreateDialog').hide()" update="display" process="@this" immediate="true" resetValues="true"/>

    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Excerpts of the AbstractController.java class:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Class<T> itemClass;
    private T selected;
    private Collection<T> items;
    private List<T> filteredItems;

    private enum PersistAction {

        CREATE,
        DELETE,
        UPDATE
    }

    public AbstractController() {
    }

    public AbstractController(Class<T> itemClass) {
        this.itemClass = itemClass;
    }

    public void setSelected(T selected) {
        if (selected != null) {
            if (this.selected == null || !this.selected.equals(selected)) {
                this.selected = this.ejbFacade.findWithParents(selected);
                this.setChildrenEmptyFlags();
            }
        } else {
            this.selected = null;
        }
    }

    protected void setEmbeddableKeys() {
    }

    protected void initializeEmbeddableKey() {
    }

    public Collection<T> getItems() {
        if (itemClass.getSimpleName().equals("Demandas")) {
            if (sessionPrefixo == 9600) {
                items = this.ejbFacade.findAll();
            } else {
                items = this.ejbFacade.findAllVenceHojeByNomeUorPos(uorPosDiageJurisdiciona);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    public void save(ActionEvent event) {
        String msg = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/adeBundle").getString(itemClass.getSimpleName() + "Updated");
        persist(PersistAction.UPDATE, msg);

        if (!isValidationFailed()) {
            // Update the existing entity inside the item list
            List<T> itemList = refreshItem(this.selected, this.items);

            // If the original list has changed (it is a new object)
            if (this.items != itemList) {
                this.setItems(itemList);
            }
            // Also refresh the filteredItems list in case the user has filtered the DataTable
            if (filteredItems != null) {
                refreshItem(this.selected, this.filteredItems);
            }
        }
    }

    public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {
        String msg = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/adeBundle").getString(itemClass.getSimpleName() + "Created");
        persist(PersistAction.CREATE, msg);

        if (!isValidationFailed()) {
            items = null; // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
            lazyItems = null; // Invalidate list of lazy items to trigger re-query.
        }
    }

    private void persist(PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
        if (selected != null) {
            this.setEmbeddableKeys();
            try {
                if (persistAction != PersistAction.DELETE) {
                    this.ejbFacade.edit(selected);
                } else {
                    this.ejbFacade.remove(selected);
                }
                this.setChildrenEmptyFlags();
                JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);
            } catch (EJBException ex) {
                Throwable cause = JsfUtil.getRootCause(ex.getCause());
                if (cause != null) {
                    if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                        ConstraintViolationException excp = (ConstraintViolationException) cause;
                        for (ConstraintViolation s : excp.getConstraintViolations()) {
                            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(s.getMessage());
                        }
                    } else {
                        String msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
                        if (msg.length() > 0) {
                            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
                        } else {
                            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/adeBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            }
        }
    }

    public T prepareCreate(ActionEvent event) {
        T newItem;
        try {
            newItem = itemClass.newInstance();
            this.selected = newItem;
            initializeEmbeddableKey();
            return newItem;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isValidationFailed() {
        return JsfUtil.isValidationFailed();
    }

    public String getComponentMessages(String clientComponent, String defaultMessage) {
        return JsfUtil.getComponentMessages(clientComponent, defaultMessage);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initParams() {
        Object paramItems = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get(itemClass.getSimpleName() + "_items");
        if (paramItems != null) {
            setItems((Collection<T>) paramItems);
        }
    }

    private List<T> refreshItem(T item, Collection<T> items) {

        List<T> itemList;
        if (this.items instanceof List) {
            itemList = (List<T>) items;
        } else {
            itemList = new ArrayList<>(items);
        }
        int i = itemList.indexOf(item);
        if (i >= 0) {
            try {
                itemList.set(i, item);
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
                return refreshItem(item, new ArrayList<>(items));
            }
        }
        return itemList;
    }

    public AbstractFacade<T> getEjbFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public void setEjbFacade(AbstractFacade<T> ejbFacade) {
        this.ejbFacade = ejbFacade;
    }
}
```

Excerpt of the AbstractFacade.java class:

```
[...]
public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
[...]
```

As mentioned in the comments, this is the reference for Demandas table:

[image: image for Demandas datatable id reference]

Please, can someone help me to resolve it ?

Comment: Open the browser console (F12). Which is the exact id you've got for `datalist`? It should match your reference here.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker, as we can see in the image I've posted in the question, the reference id (yellow circled) in the browser is the same in the code of CreateAnotacao.jsf: `<p:commandButton actionListener="#{anotacoesController.saveNew}" value="Save" update="display, :DemandasListForm:datalist, :growl" [...]`. Any other hint, please ?